# How to assign multiple enum value to same enum variable in c++?

Tags: c++

For example，we initialize an instance of enum.

```
enum weekdays {Saturday, Sunday, Tuesday,Wednesday, Thursday, Friday} weekend;
```

and can we  make `weekend` assigned both `Saturday and sunday`？

Comment: Hint: Powers of 2 and bitmasks...

Comment: Do you understand that enumerator values are just numbers? Which by default start at 0 and increment by 1?

Comment: @Sean - That doesn't assign both values to `weekend`. It will not be equal to either.

Comment: @StoryTeller - I'm aware of that. I'm trying to provide some pointers about what he'd need to change in his example (ie the values of the days)/

Comment: @Sean - I know *you* know. But giving a hint like that is only likely to confuse the OP. He doesn't seem to grasp basics here. So my comment is actually geared more towards *him*.

Comment: @StoryTeller thank you,my english is not good.But i already search lots of web pages in google，but i can ’ t get the answer.So thank you very very much and it 's my first question in stackoverflow.

Comment: @Sean Sorry,i will improve that.

Comment: *"and can we make `weekend` assigned `Saturday` and `Sunday`?"* -- only for the weeks when Saturday and Sunday are on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very messy to use same type for enumeration and collection of days. You should differentiate between `WeekDay` as symbols of days and collections of days as in `Weekend`. Look at `int` type. Variable `int something` could contain only one number. If you want more, you have to use collection: array, `vector` etc.

I assume that you want to create collections of week days where each day appears only once. For this we usually use sets.

This answer contains samples using `std::set`, then `std::bitset`, and custom class.

Sample for `std::set`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

enum WeekDay { Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday };

int main()
{
    std::set<WeekDay>   Weekend{ WeekDay::Saturday, WeekDay::Sunday };
    // For older compilers can be replaced with:
    // std::set<WeekDay>    Weekend;
    // Weekend.insert( WeekDay::Saturday );
    // Weekend.insert( WeekDay::Sunday );

    WeekDay today = WeekDay::Wednesday;

    // There is no Weekend.contains( today )
    // nor something likie Pascal
    // today in Weekend

    // Not so pretty
    if ( Weekend.find( today ) != Weekend.end() )
    //alternative:
    //if ( Weekend.count( today ) )
        std::cout << "Weekend :)\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Not weekend :(\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately it isn't looking pretty or elegant. I'm open for improvement.

And `std::bitset` version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

enum WeekDay { Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday };

int main()
{
    // I don't like this. Number of elements = last element + 1.
    std::bitset<WeekDay::Friday+1>  Weekend;
    Weekend[ WeekDay::Saturday ] = true;
    Weekend[ WeekDay::Sunday ] = true;

    WeekDay today = WeekDay::Wednesday;

    if ( Weekend[ today ] )
        std::cout << "Weekend :)\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Not weekend :(\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And custom solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

enum WeekDay { Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday };

class WeekDays
{
public:
    WeekDays() : set( 0 ) {}

    // For older compilers just omit this constructor.    
    WeekDays( const std::initializer_list<WeekDay>& init )
        : set( 0 )
    {
        for ( auto it = init.begin() ; it != init.end() ; ++it )
            insert( *it );
    }

    void insert( WeekDay d )
    {
        assert( d >= WeekDay::Saturday && d < WeekDay::Friday && d >= 0 && d <= 31 );
        set |= 1 << d;
    }

    bool contains( WeekDay d )
    {
        assert( d >= WeekDay::Saturday && d < WeekDay::Friday && d >= 0 && d <= 31 );
        return ( set & ( 1 << d ) ) != 0;
    }

private:
    unsigned int    set;
};

int main()
{
    WeekDays    Weekend{ WeekDay::Saturday, WeekDay::Sunday };
    // For older compilers can be replaced with:
    // WeekDays Weekend;
    // Weekend.insert( WeekDay::Saturday );
    // Weekend.insert( WeekDay::Sunday );

    WeekDay     today = WeekDay::Wednesday;
    if ( Weekend.contains( today ) )
        std::cout << "Weekend :)\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Not weekend :(\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank  for  your answer sincerely；And i will read it conscientiously.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare your enum as power of two.
for E.g

```
enum weekdays {Saturday  =0 , Sunday = 1, Tuesday = 2,Wednesday = 4, Thursday = 8, Friday= 16} weekend;
```

And now you can assign more than one enum by using | operator between them.

To check if any enum is set use oprator &

Comment: powers of 2 can get typos when they get large. I've always preferred `(1<<0)`, `(1<<1)`, `(1<<2)`, etc.  Also, prefer that every name has at least one bit set (Your Saturday has no bits set).